# How to make Sql query which will take search terms having keywords like AND OR () and combinations of these

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, dynamic, keyword

**Requirement:**
We have to develop a search feature wherein user will enter search terms into a Textbox. These terms will be searched in different columns (title, description, comments) of a table.

Examples;

Covid - *should search for records which have word Covid*

"Covid 19 in July" - *should search for records which have "Covid 19 in July" has a complete matching string*

Covid OR Corona - *should search for records which have word Covid or word Corona*

Covid AND Corona - *should search for records which have words Covid and corona*

Corona OR Covid AND Virus - *should search for records which could have word Corona but must have words Covid and Virus*

Moreover user can overload these combinations.

**Our current Approach:**

Currently we are relying on basic approach of identifying all the keywords within the string and trying to generate dynamic SQL query which will have WHERE clause accordingly.

**Our Question:**

The approach we are taking is quite conventional, furthermore generation of the dynamic query and it's execution has performance hit. Though we after lot of search are not able to find any working samples, articles, algorithms, links we belief that there should be better ways to achieve this. Thus, looking for such pointers.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQLSERVER the best way to search words or phrases within a text is to use the [fulltext search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15).

Before you should change the structure of your table by putting all the columns in one and after implement it.

With fulltext search you can search:

- One or more specific words or phrases (simple term)
- A word or a phrase where the words begin with specified text (prefix term)
- Inflectional forms of a specific word (generation term)
- A word or phrase close to another word or phrase (proximity term)
  Synonymous forms of a specific word (thesaurus)
- Words or phrases using weighted values (weighted term)

Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) for many query of example.

Below the difference between Fulltext and LIKE search:

> In contrast to full-text search, the LIKE Transact-SQL predicate works on character patterns only. Also, you cannot use the LIKE predicate to query formatted binary data. Furthermore, a LIKE query against a large amount of unstructured text data is much slower than an equivalent full-text query against the same data. A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows that are returned.

Comment: Did you try it?